# custom post type with new term not displaying in archive

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type 'vehicles', which has the 'taxonomy' manufacturer.

I created the term 'audi' before adding any posts and posts associated with this term appear just fine using the default wp loop on the template `archive-vehicles`. However if I add a new term such as 'ford' and then assign an existing post to this  term, the post doesn't show in the archive? If I assign the term 'audi' and 'ford' to a post it then appears in the archive?

Can anyone think why this is happening and how to resolve it?

The taxonomy in functions file:

```
function create_manufacturer_hierarchical_taxonomy() {
$labels = array(
'name' => _x( 'Manufacturer', 'taxonomy general name' ),
'singular_name' => _x( 'Manufacturer', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Manufacturers' ),
'all_items' => __( 'All Manufacturers' ),
'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Manufacturer' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Manufacturer:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Manufacturer' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Manufacturer' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Manufacturer' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Manufacturer Name' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Manufacturers' ),
      );   

      register_taxonomy('manufacturer',array('vehicles'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'manufacturer' ),
      ));
    }
```

The custom post type in the functions file:

```
function create_post_type_cars()
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('manufacturer', 'vehicles'); 
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('body', 'vehicles'); 
    register_post_type('vehicles',
        array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Vehicles', 'cars'),
            'singular_name' => __('Vehicle', 'cars'),
            'add_new' => __('Add New', 'cars'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Vehicle', 'cars'),
             'edit' => __('Edit', 'cars'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Vehicle', 'cars'),
            'new_item' => __('New Vehicle', 'cars'),
            'view' => __('View Vehicle', 'cars'),
            'view_item' => __('View Vehicle', 'cars'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Vehicles', 'cars'),
            'not_found' => __('No Vehicles found', 'cars'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Vehicles found in Trash', 'cars')
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/img/icons/portfolios-icon.png',       
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'thumbnail'
        ), 
        'can_export' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array(
            'manufacturer',
            'body'
        )
    ));
}
```

Comment: have you tried to clear all possible cache layers? (plugin, memcached, varnish, cloudflare, cdn etc.) or just add some ?a=b paramer to URL which doesn't work properly

Comment: How do I clear the cache?

Comment: Looking at the database, it seems as though new terms aren't being added to the wp_term_taxonomy table?

Comment: Where have you called create_post_type_cars, create_manufacturer_hierarchical_taxonomy functions? Which file, which filters? You can share the code where you run these 2 functions

Comment: This seems to be related to the plugin "Search & Filter Pro" as disabling it resolves the issue?